# namespace conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Site
{
    public abstract class General
    {

        private static string _version;

        public static string Version { get { return _version; } }

        static General()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
            _version = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
        }

    }
}
```

The code works fine and I can get the version anywhere I need accessing `Site.General.Version`. Now I'm trying to use the inline tag `<% = Site.General.Version %>` but I'm getting a error message saying `System.ComponentModel.ISite` does not contain a definition or 'General'.... I think there's a namespace conflict because of the *interface* `ISite`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think you forgot to post the ASPX code.

Comment: I did not. <% = Site.General.Version %>.

Comment: <%= Global.Site.General.Version %> might do it for you.

Comment: @Travis The namespace Global does not exist in the current context. I'm using it in the masterpage.

Comment: Ahh, I haven't used this ever, so my syntax was wrong. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx global::Site.General.Version. It looks like you got it by adding the namespace though, so you shouldn't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your aspx

```
 <%@ Import Namespace="Site" %>
```

And change your code like this

```
 <%= General.Version %>
```

**EDIT**

This is the syntax to do it for all pages on web.config

```
<system.web>
      <pages>
           <namespaces>
                <add namespace="Site" />
           </namespaces>
      </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Is there another solution? I don't really want to import the namespace everywhere.

Comment: @user1330271: added a way to do it globally on web.config

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend changing the name of either the namespace or the class. You can *sometimes* get it to work, but this will come back and bite you. And the compiler errors are very unhelpful, which is especially bad as this bites you on refactoring, which are often done a different time than when the code was written. I speak from experience - bad idea.

Comment: I have experienced no problems at all until now. In fact, I didn't know the ISite interface until now! How can I change the entire solution root namespace without a headache?

Comment: Search and replace `namespace Site` by `namespace SomOtherName` this will fix both namespace declaration and usage

Comment: Yeh, but I still have the solution name. The folder. The subversion. It's not simple like that. But thank you, I'm gonna do that as soon as possible.

Comment: I changed the namespace and assembly names after all. Thank you.